# How do I combine stochastic policy with Q-value Iteration?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am trying to use a stochastic policy in my q-value iteration algorithm. As I understand it, stochastic policy is a probability of choosing an action from a particular state. On the other hand, Q-value is a value of being in state-action pair. How do I combine both?

Comment: You might consider asking this question on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ instead/in addition to here, especially if this is a pure theory question and not tied to a particular technology or language.

Comment: How do I move the question or do I post a new one there?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily move it, as you may get some answers here. Questions can be moved by moderators, but if you don't get any answers here after a while I'd say just ask a new one there.

Answer (score 2):

One example of this is the epsilon-greedy approach used to increase exploration during Q-learning.

In this instance, you take the best action, as defined by Q(s,a), with probability epsilon (between 0 and 1), and you take a random action with probability 1-epsilon.